# In my react application this file 'main.chunk.js' takes lot of time , how can i improve performance of my React Application?how to minimize load time

Tags: reactjs, web, optimization, lazy-loading, performance-testing

[image]

How can I improve the performance of my react application, is there any solution to more optimize reactJs application.

Comment: Use React router's lazy and suspense

Comment: Is your app setup using CRA? Or is it a custom setup with your own Webpack (or some other module bundler) configuration?

Comment: Actually I am already using lazy component in application but it still not working fine